# how can I know if a task is completed

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a grid that loads lots of information when a row is selected - 7 more grids and a DevExpress report need to load, and it takes a lot of time

I put all the methods into tasks to speed up the process.

But if another row is selected before the previous one finishes loading, it causes errors.

I would like to know how to check if the task is finished and the either wait or cancel the task before loading again with new data. (I am new to asynchronous programming)

This is an example of my tasks (there are 8 of them, each called one after another):

```
    private async void LoadSSNs()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => grdSSNs.DataSource = ICTBLL.GetData(ID));
    }
```

How can I change it into a Task object that I can check if complete?

Comment: Look at the return type of `Task.Run()`.

Comment: You can return a `Task` or `Task<T>` and use that to determine if it's completed. Also you can use a `CancellationToken` and cooperative cancellation to cancel previous tasks. Right now `async void` is unawawaitable and fire-and-forgot so you won't have any idea if it's done or failed etc.

Comment: var rtnResult = await Task.Run(() => MethodWithBooleanRetrunOrSomething); 
If(rtnResult){ //do something }

Answer (score 8):

You should almost never have a `void` return type with async/await (there are exceptions, but start with that).  Your method needs to return a `Task` so you have something to wait on or check for completion status.

```
private async Task LoadSSNs()
{
    await Task.Run(() => grdSSNs.DataSource = ICTBLL.GetData(ID));
}
```

How you determine if the task is complete depends on what you need to do.  If you need to do some work while the task runs asynchronously, you could do this:

```
var t = LoadSSNs();

// do something while task is running.

t.Wait(); // this is one option.
if (t.Status == TaskStatus.Faulted) { } // handle problems from task.
```

If you have more work to do while the task completes, you could do something like this:

```
while(!t.IsCompleted)
{
    // do some other work.
}
```

Again, what you do with the task is up to you; the important part is you need to return an awaitable `Task` from your async method.

Comment: Note: you can't call `t.Wait();` then check `t.Status == TaskStatus.Faulted` since `t.Wait()` [throws an exception](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Wait) if the task had errors (and the status would be `TaskStatus.Faulted`). You need `try-catch` to do that check properly.